# Notification does not appear - how to fix that?

Tags: java, android

so I but a Button and set a listener for it so method sendNotification() below is executed. However once I click the button nothing happen even the catch statement
Note that the code is written in fragment so I made a variables context and activity then initialize them

```
  activity= getActivity();
```

`context= getActivity().getBaseContext();`

```
 public void sendNotification() {
    try{
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder;
        builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context,"id");
       builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
        .setContentTitle("Notifications Example")
               .setContentText("This is a test notification");

       Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, activity.getClass());
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);

        // Add as notification
       NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        manager.notify(0, builder.build());

}
                    catch (Exception e){MainActivity.prefConfig.displayToast("something is wrong with the method.. ");}
}
```

Comment: Which API level are you testing this on? On Android Oreo (27) and above, you will need to set a notification channel for it to be visible.

Comment: @TheGamer007 it is API 26

Comment: Right, Oreo starts at API 26. My bad. Adding an answer.

Comment: @TheGamer007 you are right I set a channel and it works thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the [Create and Manage Notification Channels](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/channels) guide:

> If you target Android 8.0 (API level 26) and post a notification without specifying a notification channel, the notification does not appear and the system logs an error.

The full instructions are available in the guide, but you essentially need to create a Notification Channel first as follows:

```
private void createNotificationChannel() {
    // Create the NotificationChannel, but only on API 26+ because
    // the NotificationChannel class is new and not in the support library
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        CharSequence name = getString(R.string.channel_name);
        String description = getString(R.string.channel_description);
        int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, importance);
        channel.setDescription(description);
        // Register the channel with the system; you can't change the importance
        // or other notification behaviors after this
        NotificationManager notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }
}
```

After which the same `CHANNEL_ID` must be passed as the second parameter when creating the `NotificationCompat.Builder` object. (where you have passed "id")

Answer (score 0):

**This might help you out**

NotificationCompat.Builder constructor requires that you provide a channel ID. This is required for compatibility with Android 8.0 (API level 26) and higher, but is ignored by older versions.

Before you can deliver the notification on Android 8.0 and higher, you must register your app's notification channel with the system by passing an instance of NotificationChannel to createNotificationChannel(). So the following code is blocked by a condition on the SDK_INT version:

```
private void createNotificationChannel() {
// Create the NotificationChannel, but only on API 26+ because
// the NotificationChannel class is new and not in the support library
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    CharSequence name = getString(R.string.channel_name);
    String description = getString(R.string.channel_description);
    int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;
    NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, importance);
    channel.setDescription(description);
    // Register the channel with the system; you can't change the importance
    // or other notification behaviors after this
    NotificationManager notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
    notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
}}
```

Every notification should respond to a tap, usually to open an activity in your app that corresponds to the notification. To do so, you must specify a content intent defined with a PendingIntent object and pass it to setContentIntent().

The following snippet shows how to create a basic intent to open an activity when the user taps the notification:

```
// Create an explicit intent for an Activity in your app
Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlertDetails.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);

NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
        .setContentTitle("My notification")
        .setContentText("Hello World!")
        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
        // Set the intent that will fire when the user taps the notification
        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
        .setAutoCancel(true);
```

Show the notification
To make the notification appear, call NotificationManagerCompat.notify(), passing it a unique ID for the notification and the result of NotificationCompat.Builder.build().

```
NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);

// notificationId is a unique int for each notification that you must define
notificationManager.notify(notificationId, mBuilder.build());
```

Remember to save the notification ID that you pass to NotificationManagerCompat.notify() because you'll need it later if you want to update or remove the notification.